# Firebase / Firestore not getting document and running code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a document from firebase in swift. However the line isn't being run and is not getting the data.

This is my code:

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("chats").document(userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("messages").document("variable").getDocument { (document, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("error getting document")
        }
        else{
            let documentData = document!.data()
            let startNumOfMessages = documentData!["numOfMessages"] as! Int
            var messageArray: Array<String> = []
            if startNumOfMessages > 0 {
                for message in 1...startNumOfMessages{
                    print(message)
                    //THIS LINE ISNT RUNNING
                    db.collection("chats").document(self.userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("messages").document("\(message)").getDocument { (messageDoc, err) in
                        if err != nil{
                            print("Error getting message \(message)")
                        }
                        else{
                            if messageDoc!.exists && messageDoc != nil{
                                let messData = messageDoc!.data()
                                print(messData!["message"]!)
                                messageArray.append(messData!["message"] as! String)
                            }
                            else{
                                print("error in document")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Display them
                for num in 0...messageArray.count{
                    let label = UILabel()
                    label.text = messageArray[num]
                    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line below the comment is the line that isn't running. And the line that says `label.text = messageArray[num]` displays an error

> Fatal error: Index out of range

Showing it doesn't get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the asynchronous way use `DispatchGroup` ( numbered from 1 to 4 )

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("chats").document(userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("messages").document("variable").getDocument { (document, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print("error getting document")
    }
    else{
        let documentData = document!.data()
        let startNumOfMessages = documentData!["numOfMessages"] as! Int
        var messageArray: Array<String> = []
        if startNumOfMessages > 0 {
            let g = DispatchGroup() /// 1
            for message in 1...startNumOfMessages{
                print(message)
                //THIS LINE ISNT RUNNING
                g.enter() /// 2
                db.collection("chats").document(self.userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("messages").document("\(message)").getDocument { (messageDoc, err) in
                    if err != nil{
                        print("Error getting message \(message)")
                    }
                    else{
                        if messageDoc!.exists && messageDoc != nil{
                            let messData = messageDoc!.data()
                            print(messData!["message"]!)
                            messageArray.append(messData!["message"] as! String) 
                        }
                        else{
                            print("error in document")
                        }
                    }
                    g.leave() /// 3
                }
            }
            g.notify(queue: .main) {  /// 4
                //Display them
                for num in 0...messageArray.count{
                    let label = UILabel()
                    label.text = messageArray[num]
                    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it is doing the same thing but earlier can you help with that? @sh_khan